# Loading 15k records in Angularjs multiselect textbox

Tags: java, html, css, angularjs, spring

I am trying to load 15K records in the multiselect textbox. I have used ng-repeat but is not loading 15K records in any browser. I have changed the code to ng-options and it's working in Mozilla Firefox but  not working on internet explorer.I am getting error saying the script is blocked after sometime.

I need to make it work on IE 11.

I have considered the options like infinite scrolling, but exiting functionality has the search option on all 15K records.
Data is coming fine from back-end but the problem is with angularjs to load all Huge data set, I need to send the selected options to back-end, So I need the control on the data.

Here is the code I am using:

```
TaskInfo.html

    //tasks hold of 15K records around
    <div ng-options="task.name as task.taskId for task in tasks> </div>

TaskController.js

$http.get('taskDetails').success(function(response){
$scope.tasks=response;
});
```

Please let me know any options to make it work on IE 11?

Comment: why so many records? An user can't handle that. Use paging (or infinite scrolling) instead (in both backend an frontend), it will be better in performance and usability. If you can't use paging in backend use it at least in frontend, not rendering so many items will improve performance

Comment: change your design ASAP , unless you need to carry the garbage ever.